# Paperclip 2.8 Not Using `config.paperclip_defaults` Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

For some reason, I can't get Paperclip to correctly use S3.  I've configured it just like the documentation says, but all of my environments still use the `public/system` directory for storing files.

Here's my configuration:

```
# config/application.rb

config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :default_url => "/assets/:attachment/default/:style.jpg",
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_protocol => 'https',
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id =>  ENV['S3_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key =>  ENV['S3_SECRET']
  },
  :bucket =>  ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
  :path => "/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :styles => {
    :giant  => ["600x600>"],
    :huge  => ["450x450>"],
    :large  => ["300x300>"],
    :medium => ["200x200>"],
    :small => ["100x100>"],
    :thumb => ["48x48>"],
    :profile => ["34x34>"],
    :mini => ["24x24>"]
  }
}
```

I have confirmed that all of the buckets are named correctly in my `application.yml` and the `S3_KEY` and `S3_SECRET` are both correct as well.

I'm using `gem "paperclip", "~> 2.8"` as this is an older project that we're not worried about updating just yet.

## Update

I realize now that a previous developer changed the paperclip version from `~> 3.1` to `~> 2.8` to clear up some dependency issues before turning over the project... However it was literally right before he handed it over to me and he never knew that it messed up the configuration.  Version 2.8 doesn't set global defaults like 3.0 does, so the `config.paperclip_defaults` are apparently meaningless in the version I have.

Instead, I've updated my `application.rb` file to set the defaults on the `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options` hash:

```
# config/application.rb

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url]     = "/assets/:attachment/default/:style.jpg"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage]         = :s3
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol]     = 'https'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials]  = {
  :access_key_id =>  ENV['S3_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key =>  ENV['S3_SECRET']
}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:bucket]          =  ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path]            = "/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:styles]          => {
  :giant  => ["600x600>"],
  :huge  => ["450x450>"],
  :large  => ["300x300>"],
  :medium => ["200x200>"],
  :small => ["100x100>"],
  :thumb => ["48x48>"],
  :profile => ["34x34>"],
  :mini => ["24x24>"]
}
```

Comment: @user2954587 there is no error in my log, just the fact that I'm trying to get paperclip to store images in my S3 bucket, but it's still storing them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my question, `gem "paperclip", "~> 2.8"` doesn't respond to the `config.paperclip_defaults` hash and instead gets defaults from the `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options` hash.